# Does the ps4 ALWAYS come up with an error message if you turn it off incorrectly?

Tags: ps4

Wanted to know whether the ps4 always comes up with an error message regardless if it's turned off incorrectly. For example if you lost power while it was still shutting down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, it will always tell you that it was shut off incorrectly and then it will try and find and recover any data that may have been lost due to the incorrect shutdown.

[Here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-4-Support/INFO-PS4-Error-Codes/td-p/42154857) is a list of all know error codes and their fixes.

Comment: Would it pop up If if was turned off while shutting down though ? And could the actual system be damaged in any way?

Comment: Yes, and yes it has happened to many people when the ps4 first came out and it was called 'bricked'

Comment: I mean if it lost power while shutting down. Would the error message still pop up then

Comment: No you would have to turn it on again, as it would have no power to show the message.

Comment: Yes but would the error message definately Pop up in that case

Comment: Yes it would, I have had this happen to me before.